# Healthy APFS volume trapped by broken container

Tags: macos, container, apfs

How do I mount a healthy APFS volume belonging to a broken APFS container? The volume has FileVault enabled. All data sits on an external USB disk.

The external USB disk was prepared with filevault enabled. It worked correctly for a few months. One day, I just unmounted the disk, as usual, and stored it away. The day after the disk presented the corrupted container. The volume is healthy, however, because I can list its content using a third party tool that first asks for the filevault password.

The aim is to unlock it and mount it using the command line, as I need to rsync the full contents to a new disk.

```
>diskutil apfs list
APFS Containers (2 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 FE1CF197-187D-408D-8769-DC6629899818
|   ====================================================
|   [...]
|
+-- Container ERROR -69808
    ======================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk3
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      ERROR -69620
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   ERROR -69524
    Capacity Not Allocated:       ERROR -69524
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk2s2 E621C1C5-424C-49F8-B83E-43AD1AEE0D47
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk2s2
    |   Size:                       999860912128 B (999.9 GB)
    |
    +-> No Volumes
```

The omitted part [...] is disk1, being the running system.

```
>sudo fsck_apfs -n /dev/disk2s2    
** Checking volume.
** Checking the container superblock.
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** Checking the object map.
error: /dev/disk3s1 is not encrypted
** The volume /dev/disk2s2 could not be verified completely.

>sudo diskutil apfs unlock disk2s2 -nomount
disk2s2 is not an APFS Volume

>sudo diskutil mount readOnly -mountPoint /mnt disk2s2 
Volume on disk2s2 failed to mount because it appears to be an APFS Physical Store
See "diskutil apfs list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this container break during encryption?

Check the status of the encryption in Terminal

```
diskutil apfs list
```

Since the drive is external, and probably will not mount in the original device.

```
diskutil apfs unlockVolume -nomount
```

(Use your account password to unlock it).

I had the same issue with an SSD that failed during an upgrade due to bad blocks, and ended up doing this, then using [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com) to scan the current contents of the drive. It should pick it up once it is unlocked, even though it is not mounted. It works in read-only mode, which is beneficial for the integrity of the data.

Comment: Try unlocking the volume, then use DiskDrill to scan the current contents of the disk. I had full success with an SSD that ran out of writes. My container could only unlock not mount. It should be able to read the files from the physical store, and handle creating a new container shell for you to backup data to a different drive. Also, run this from a different device where the hard drive you are trying to recover is NOT the boot drive. This would be the next thing I try. Not sure you can actually repair the container, but just create a new one.